# Send a logic 1 from a USB port

Tags: python, windows, usb

I have an electronic system waiting to be triggered (no microcontroller for now).
My laptop only has USB ports.

I want to trigger it using voice recognition (this part is ok).

For now the only think I can think of is :

Once the right keyword is detected, send a 19 KHz sine on the audio output, because it's inaudible, for 0.1 seconds and uses a microcontroller analog port to detect it.

I only have microcontroller with no USB support available and I've never used a USB connection.

I'm not looking for something perfect, a dirty solution would be all right, this is just to do a prank tomorrow.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use Serial? Arduino has great support for it

Comment: no serial port on the laptop or usb to serial converter at home, I have 20h to finish now.
I'm already building the 19Khz version but if anyone has a better idea I'm all ears.

Comment: Which uC do you have?

Comment: mostly 16F628A from microchip, edit : and I just found a 16F877A

Comment: Oh I'm stupid, The audio line in't used, I just have to unplug the speakers, send audio, put a low pass filter to get an average and use a comparator to know when it needs to be triggered, that will do it for now.

Comment: well that sucks, so much horse power and no easy way to use it directly. I'll get some of those FTDI chips, I can see a lot of use for these.

Comment: i'd suggest a USB to Serial converter, it might make things really simple

Answer (score 3):

Use a USB to Serial Port adapter with your microcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

You might use a tone decoder (LM567 is typical) to detect that and
only that frequency, and give a logic output. [TI LM567](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm567.pdf) 
These devices can be driven from a microphone, and are insensitive to
other sounds they might pick up, so your laptop could switch the target
circuit wirelessly.